How to add SMS OTP validation after username and password authentication in Keycloak with a custom Angular UI?
I am currently using Keycloak for authentication and authorization in my application. My setup involves a custom login form built in Angular that collects the user's username and password. The form submits these credentials to Keycloak’s token endpoint (/protocol/openid-connect/token), and upon success, I receive a valid access token.
Now, I want to enhance security by adding an SMS OTP validation step after username and password authentication. The process I want to implement is as follows:

User enters their username and password in the Angular app.
The credentials are sent to Keycloak’s token endpoint for validation.
If authentication succeeds:
An OTP is generated and sent to the user’s registered mobile number.
The backend handles OTP generation and sending via an SMS provider (e.g., Twilio, AWS SNS, etc.).
User is prompted to enter the OTP in a second custom Angular form.
The entered OTP is validated via a Keycloak's API.
If the OTP is valid, the user is considered authenticated, and they proceed to the application.

Constraints:

I am not using Keycloak’s built-in UI or authentication flows.
All forms (username/password and OTP input) should reside in the Angular app.
Keycloak stores the user’s mobile number as a custom user attribute (e.g., mobileNumber).
I would prefer to handle OTP validation and logic using Keycloak and use its token-based authentication for the initial step.
I have already tried with implementation provided in https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-2fa-sms-authenticator ,but I want it using my custom UI.

